# Codeigniter clear session after user searches

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination, session-variables

I'm working with a search function that paginates the pages inside codeigniter. So I am saving the search term in a session so when you switch pages the term is still available. I am having a slight issue with it though, it's saving everything you input.

I know I need to clear the sessions using this

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('searchChal');
```

but I'm just nit sure where to put it. I've tried placing at the begin and end of function, but it clears the session too fast and when clicking the next page the session is no longer there.

Is there any way I can clear the session when a user inputs another value? Or am I just missing something?

Here is my function

```
public function searchChallenges(){
//This function allows you to search through all the challenges
    $config["base_url"] = base_url()."index.php/story/searchChallenges";
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->data_model->searchChal_count();
    $config["per_page"] = 1;
    $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
    $choice = $config["total_rows"] / $config["per_page"];
    $config["num_links"] = round($choice);
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $searchTerm = $this->input->post("searchC", TRUE);

    if($searchTerm) {
        $searchChal= $this->input->post("searchC", TRUE);
         $this->session->set_userdata('searchChal', $searchChal);

     }elseif($this->session->userdata('searchChal')){
         $this->search = $this->session->userdata('searchChal');

     }else{
        $searchTerm ="";
     }

        if (empty($this->user)) {
            $this->load->view('header_view', array(
                'cSearch' =>  $this->session->userdata('searchChal'),
            ));
            $story = $this->story_model->searchChal($config['per_page'], $page);
            if (! isset($story[0]->challenge_id)){
                $this->load->view('noSearchChal_view');
            }else{
                $this->load->view('challenge_view', array(
                    'query' => $this->story_model->searchChal($config['per_page'], $page),
                        'links' => $this->pagination->create_links(),
                        'searchTerm' =>   $this->session->userdata('searchChal'),
                )); 
            }   
            $this->load->view('footer_view');   
        }else{
            $this->load->view('header_view',array(
                'user' => $this->users_model->getUser($this->user->user_id),
                'cSearch' =>  $this->input->post("searchC"),
            ));
            $story = $this->story_model->searchChal($config['per_page'], $page);
            if (! isset($story[0]->challenge_id)){
                $this->load->view('noSearchChal_view');
            }else{
                $this->load->view('challenge_view', array(
                    'query' => $this->story_model->searchChal($config['per_page'], $page),
                    'links' => $this->pagination->create_links(),
                    'admin' => $this->admin_model->adminSearchChal(),
                    'searchTerm' =>  $searchTerm,
                )); 
            }   
            $this->load->view('footer_view');   
        }
}
```

I would greatly appreciate some help!

Comment: You should be passing the search term via the url, so the user can have multiple searches open simultaneously and the results page is bookmarkable and shareable.

Comment: why would I want them to have multiple searches open? I only want them to be able to search one thing at a time. Plus, that's not my issue, my issue is clearing the sessions.

Comment: This is an internal search though, not one that I want to be bookmarked or be able to searched. This is more of a if you are a registered user and you want a more detailed search of one small section of the site. It's a nice to have feature. And like I said I am only having trouble clearing the sessions I put in place because of the pagination, the rest of the search works fine.

Answer (score 0):

put this after footer view :-

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('searchChal');
```